# How to add simple product to grouped product as Associated products?

Tags: product

I have grouped product with the name Group1. And also I have category with the same name(Group1). I have several simple product under the Group1 category. How to add these products under this category only as Associated product to grouped product programmatically?

I got a product collection under the category named as Group1 by

```
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection') 
                      ->addCategoryFilter($category);
```

Now i want to add these products to the Grouped product as Associated product

If anybody know, please help me guys

Answer (score 1):

If simple products are under Group1 category try following code to associate them to grouped product of this category:

```
    $productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addCategoryFilter($category);
    $relation_data     = array(); //Grouped - child relation data
    $groupedProduct    = false; //Grouped product
    foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
        if ($product->getTypeId() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_GROUPED) {
            $groupedProduct = $product;
        } else if ($product->getTypeId() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE) {
            $relation_data[$product->getId()] = array(
                'qty'      => 1,
                'position' => 0,
                'ids'      => $product->getId()
            );
        }
    }
    if ($groupedProduct) {
        $groupedProduct->setGroupedLinkData($relation_data);
        try {
            $groupedProduct->save();
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            Mage::logException($ex);
        }
    }
```